# Regex for Validating Geo Coordinates

Tags: javascript, regex, geolocation

All,

I have created below regex (javascript regex) for validating geo location coordinates as follows:

```
(42.969142, -81.237232)
(42, -81)
(-42, +81)
etc
```

I have the following regex expression that works in an online validator but doesn't work in the browser, please help:

Regex:

```
\([-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\,\s*[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\)
```

Tested here and it works:

http://www.regextester.com/

My javascript code:

```
var regexCoords = "\([-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\,\s*[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexCoords);
    var validCoords = regex.test(streetAddr);
```

Comment: `var regexCoords = /\([-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\s*\,\s*[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\)/;`

Comment: Always test at regex101.com and after testing see the *code generator* page for the code that should work.

Comment: I'm new to JS regex, why is the regex not in quotation as a string? Btw, I did look at other related stackoverflow posts about this topic and the regexes did not work.

Comment: nvm, I see the explanation at the top of the post. Thanks for help.